# .class file contains no variable names although setting to create those is activated

Tags: java, bytecode, javap, jd-gui

I try to find the reason for a strange effect with .class files. It seems like for interfaces the names of variables passed into a function are not listed, but in implementation classes they are. I stumbled across this effect while de-compiling some of my own class files with JD-Gui.

I checked this with these two files:

*Person.java*

```
public interface Person {
    public abstract void setName( String name );
    public void setAge( int age );
}
```

*PersonImpl.java*

```
public class PersonImpl implements Person {
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("This is my name: " + name);
    }
    @Override
    public void setAge(int age) {
        System.out.println("This is my age: " + age);
    }
}
```

JD-Gui returns this when decompiling:

[image: Interface shows only generic variable type info]

[image: Implementing class shows 'real' variable name]

Using `javap -verbose x.class` I get similar results: the printed method signatures differ from interface to implementing class. One misses variable names like I specified them in my source, the other has them.

I tried to answer my question studying the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf) but have to admit I failed finding my way through this document.

Is there a reason why this was designed that way ?

**Edit:**

Because of all the good answers I received I added some lines to my interface and implementation class in order to back the statements from the answer:s

*Person.java*

```
default public void yawn(int count) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            System.out.println("uaaaaah ....");
    }
```

JD-Gui is able to determine the name of the parameter:

[image: JD-Gui is able to show the name of the variable]

JavaP is able to list it in the LocalVariableTable:

[image: variable names as shown by javap]

When I add an abstract method to the implementing class and make the whole class abstract (which I need to because it contains one abstract method) ...

*PersonImpl.java*

```
public abstract void setPlanet( String planet );
```

... then JD-Gui fails to decompile this class file. But fortunately javap still is able to dump the file. All methods that are *not abstract* keep their LocalVariableTable. And the abstract method has a signature but neither Code, nor Lines or even a LocalVariableTable (this was expected)

[image: dump from javap for PersonImpls abstract method]

Comment: Are you asking why the interface parameter(s) (`String paramString`) differ in name from the implementation parameter(s) (`String name`)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I tried to express this, yes ;-)

Comment: This is more a guess than anything else but might it be due to the `abstract` keyword? When looking at this from a C++ point of view one could say: when defining a method prototype, the name of the parameter does not matter. Also it is [discouraged to use abstract on interface(-method)s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.1.1.1)

Comment: @Turing85 Good point. Because of this I added two methods, one with "abstract" and one without. Both (I don't have this on the screenshot) miss the variable name.

Comment: Similar to @Turing85 's comment, the interface's parameter names don't matter, just the parameter types. The interface is only there as a contract with the class to implement methods. The class' parameter names however, do matter due to scoping.

Comment: Aren't all interface methods public abstract anyways?

Comment: @BenKnoble that is, was the documentation says (look at the link i have posted)

Comment: @Turing85 next time I'll follow the link :P

Comment: Did some more testing. If your inteface defines a `default` method and you execute `javap -verbose ...`, you will see the variable name. Could you check with JD-Gui, whether it sees the name of a `default` method?

Comment: @Turing85 `javap -l -c` does show a `LocalVariableTable` for a default methods, and JD-Gui seems to show it as well.

Comment: @Marged The `abstract` is superfluous and is discouraged. Method definitions are implicitly abstract in interfaces (unless you provide a default method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually nothing within the class file itself that stores the name of the method parameter. If you look at [section 4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3), you'll see the following definitions for `MethodDescriptor`:

> A method descriptor represents the parameters that the method takes and the value that it returns:
>
> ```
> MethodDescriptor:
>     ( ParameterDescriptor* ) ReturnDescriptor
> A parameter descriptor represents a parameter passed to a method:
>
> ParameterDescriptor:
>     FieldType
> ```
>
> A return descriptor represents the type of the value returned from a method. It is a series of characters generated by the grammar:
>
> ```
> ReturnDescriptor:
>     FieldType
>     VoidDescriptor
>
> VoidDescriptor:
>     V
> ```
>
> The character V indicates that the method returns no value (its return type is void).

You can see this if you print out the bytecode for `Person.class` and `PersonImpl.class` using `javap -c`:

```
Compiled from "Person.java"
public interface Person {
  public abstract void setName(java.lang.String);

  public abstract void setAge(int);
}

Compiled from "PersonImpl.java"
public class PersonImpl implements Person {
  public PersonImpl();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void setName(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup
       7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      10: ldc           #5                  // String This is my name:
      12: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      15: aload_1
      16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      22: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      25: return

  public void setAge(int);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup
       7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      10: ldc           #9                  // String This is my age:
      12: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      15: iload_1
      16: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      22: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      25: return
}
```

You can see that the signature for the method says nothing about the name of the parameter; only its type.

<s>What I suspect is happening is that JD-Gui is probably using some sort of heuristic based on JavaBeans conventions to derive the name of the parameter. Since the name of the method is `setName`, it assumes that the name of the parameter is `name`. Try changing the name of the parameter to something other than `name` and see what JD-Gui prints out.</s>

Debug information, like local variables, will show up if you compile using `-g` or `-g:vars`; it does not show up by default. These show up in the `LocalVariableTable` attribute. From [section 4.7.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13):

> The `LocalVariableTable` attribute is an **optional** variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a `Code` attribute (§4.7.3). It may be used by debuggers to determine the value of a given local variable during the execution of a method.

Notice the optional part; this is why you don't see it by default. Now if you look at [section 4.7.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3) for the `Code` attribute:

> The Code attribute is a variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a method_info structure (§4.6). A `Code` attribute contains the Java Virtual Machine instructions and auxiliary information for a method, including an instance initialization method or a class or interface initialization method (§2.9).
>
> **If the method is either native or abstract, its `method_info` structure must not have a `Code` attribute in its attributes table.** Otherwise, its method_info structure must have exactly one `Code` attribute in its attributes table.

Since interface method-definitions are effectively abstract (unless you use [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)), you won't see a `LocalVariableTable` entry for them. I used the latest version of JD-Gui against `PersonImpl.class` that was **not** compiled with `-g`, and found that it did not display `name` and `age`. Instead it displayed `paramString` and `paramInt` just like you saw for `Person.class`. However, if you do compile it with the `-g` flag, you will see `name` and `age`.

Comment: I think that JD-Gui is using the `LocalVariableTable` to generate the names (execute `javap -verbose Class.class` and you will see this table). And since an Interface has no implementation, it has no `LocalVariableTable`.

Comment: @Turing85 Only if you compile with debug information (`-g` flag). Otherwise the table does not show up even if you use the `-l` flag with `javap`.

Answer (score 3):

It is due to the method being `abstract` in an interface. The information about names of method parameters is contained the [`LocalVariableTable` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13) in the bytecode which is present in the `Code` attribute:

> The `LocalVariableTable` attribute is an optional variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a `Code` (§4.7.3) attribute.

The `Code` attribute is defined as follows:

> The `Code` attribute is a variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a `method_info` (§4.6) structure. A Code attribute contains the Java Virtual Machine instructions and auxiliary information for a single method, instance initialization method (§2.9), or class or interface initialization method (§2.9). Every Java Virtual Machine implementation must recognize Code attributes. ***If the method is either `native` or `abstract`, its `method_info` structure must not have a `Code` attribute.*** Otherwise, its `method_info` structure must have exactly one `Code` attribute.

Comment: It appears that the table is only present if the `-g` flag was used during compilation, and does not exist by default. Then using `-l` with `javap` will show the table. Otherwise it doesn't show. Note it says that: *"The LocalVariableTable attribute is an **optional** variable-length attribute in the attributes table of a Code attribute (§4.7.3). It may be used by debuggers to determine the value of a given local variable during the execution of a method."*

Answer (score 0):

As explained by the other answers, the presence of a `LocalVariableTable` relies on the presence of a `Code` attribute and hence isn’t available for `abstract` methods. Note that Java 8 introduced an attribute for conserving parameter names which works independently to the debugging information. The creation of this attribute must be opted via compile-time flag:

Given your `interface`:

```
public interface Person {
    void setName(String name);
    void setAge(int age);
}
```

```
> javac Person.java

> javap -v Person
Classfile /C:/Users/pietsch/AppData/Local/Temp/Person.class
  Last modified 11.06.2015; size 159 bytes
  MD5 checksum 2fc084aa2f41b0b98e1417be7faeff8b
  Compiled from "Person.java"
public interface Person
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_INTERFACE, ACC_ABSTRACT
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #9             // Person
   #2 = Class              #10            // java/lang/Object
   #3 = Utf8               setName
   #4 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #5 = Utf8               setAge
   #6 = Utf8               (I)V
   #7 = Utf8               SourceFile
   #8 = Utf8               Person.java
   #9 = Utf8               Person
  #10 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public abstract void setName(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT

  public abstract void setAge(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
}
SourceFile: "Person.java"
```

```
> javac -parameters Person.java

> javap -v Person
Classfile /C:/Users/pietsch/AppData/Local/Temp/Person.class
  Last modified 11.06.2015; size 213 bytes
  MD5 checksum 63dfd86ff035e339baf7b9e9ae65020f
  Compiled from "Person.java"
public interface Person
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_INTERFACE, ACC_ABSTRACT
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #12            // Person
   #2 = Class              #13            // java/lang/Object
   #3 = Utf8               setName
   #4 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #5 = Utf8               MethodParameters
   #6 = Utf8               name
   #7 = Utf8               setAge
   #8 = Utf8               (I)V
   #9 = Utf8               age
  #10 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #11 = Utf8               Person.java
  #12 = Utf8               Person
  #13 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
{
  public abstract void setName(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
    MethodParameters:
      Name                           Flags
      name

  public abstract void setAge(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT
    MethodParameters:
      Name                           Flags
      age
}
SourceFile: "Person.java"
```

I don’t know whether JD-Gui is capable of using this information.

Comment: can you tell me which compile-time flag this is ?

Comment: I thought I did. When running `javac` on the command line, as shown in my second console output, the compiler option is `-parameters`. IDEs might have associated toggles, e.g. in Eclipse the checkbox is labelled “Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)”…